# JUnit Jupiter should i mock kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, spring-kafka

I'm writing a test for my user-creating operation and it includes sending a message to the kafka. Should I mock Kafka while testing this part? What is the best practice?

Also if I want to test kafka without mocking it, it normally works with kafkaTemplate autowired in userKafkaProducer , but when I run it in test, kafkaTemplate is null. How should I proceed here?

```
 @Test
    public void testCreateUserSuccess() throws UserNameExistException {
        
        UserRepository userRepo = mock(UserRepository.class);
        UserKafkaProducer userKafkaProducer = mock(UserKafkaProducer.class);
        UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepo, userKafkaProducer);

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUserName("test_user");

        when(userRepo.existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName())).thenReturn(false);

        User savedUser = new User();
        savedUser.setUserName("test_user");
        savedUser.setId("1");
        when(userRepo.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(savedUser);

        User user = userService.createUser(userDTO);

        assertNotNull(user);
        assertNotNull(user.getId());
        assertEquals(userDTO.getUserName(), user.getUserName());
        verify(userRepo, times(1)).existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName());
        verify(userRepo, times(1)).save(any(User.class));
        // Mocking the sendMessage method of UserKafkaProducer
        //doNothing().when(userKafkaProducer).sendMessage(any(User.class));
        verify(userKafkaProducer, times(1)).sendMessage(user); //mock ?

    }
```

Kafka Producer Class

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor

public class UserKafkaProducer {

private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserKafkaProducer.class);

private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

public void sendMessage(User user) {
    Message<User> message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(user)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, KafkaTopicConfig.MOVIE_SERVICE_USER_TOPIC_NAME)
            .build();
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Kafka message sent %s", message));
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);
}
}
```

Comment: mock kafkaTemplate when you are testing your userKafkaProducer.

Comment: add UserKafkaProducer code to provide you better answer.

Comment: @AwaisLatif I added UserKafkaProducer class

Comment: @AwaisLatif I suggest linking to the latest documentation

Comment: Mock kafkaTemplate bean and test sendMessage and check kafkaTemplate.send should be called 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this depends on what type of testing you are trying to achieve.

From what I can see in your code you have posted, it looks like you are trying to write unit tests. When writing unit tests, you should only focus on testing the "unit under test", in this case it looks like your `UserService` class. For a unit service test, you typically should be mocking almost everything other than the unit under test and simple data classes, including any mocking Kafka APIs. Simply put you want to isolate asant things as possible so you can focus on testing your single unit. The Kafka APIs have already been rigorously tested and you dont need to replicate that.

Having said all that, looking at your code, KafkaTemplate, will be null in the above test as you are mocking the Producer class. Within a mock there is no behaviour and no data unless you define it. This also shouldn't matter for a unit test as that behaviour is now outside the scope of the "unit under test" and you should only worry about the sendMessage function being called correctly.

However for an integration test where you are using `@SpringBootTest` (I'm assuming you are using SpringBoot from your code above), where you are testing the integration of multiple classes and the flow of your application I would use something like `@EmbeddedKafka`, which will spin up a temporary local Kafka for you to perform tests in to ensure your Kafka configuration is correct.

This is quite a good article about writing integration tests with Kafka using both @EmbeddedKafka and TestContainers: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing

Of course a lot of best practices when it comes to writing tests are purely opinionated, so it's about finding a methodology you are comfortable with that suits your risk appetite and doesn't offend your colleagues . But I find a mix of the above unit and integration tests is a solid method for achieving good coverage and confidence.